# Getting the application version using inside Burn Bootstrapper project

Tags: wpf, wix, bootstrapper, burn, wix3.10

Usually the EXE version is set in Bundle.wxs file. Is it possible to get this version in the Bootstrapper Application project where the backend engine logic for the installer is written? I have created a custom UI using WPF. I need to show the version in the UI. How can I do this? Please advice. Below is my Bootstrapper application code.

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private MINAClient minaClient;

        //constructor
        public MainViewModel(BootstrapperApplication bootstrapper)
        {

            this.IsThinking = false;

            this.Bootstrapper = bootstrapper;
            this.Bootstrapper.ApplyComplete += this.OnApplyComplete;
            this.Bootstrapper.DetectPackageComplete += this.OnDetectPackageComplete;
            this.Bootstrapper.PlanComplete += this.OnPlanComplete;
            this.Bootstrapper.DetectComplete += this.DetectComplete;

            this.Bootstrapper.CacheAcquireProgress += (sender, args) =>
            {
                this.cacheProgress = args.OverallPercentage;
                this.Progress = (this.cacheProgress + this.executeProgress) / 2;
            };
            this.Bootstrapper.ExecuteProgress += (sender, args) =>
            {
                this.executeProgress = args.OverallPercentage;
                this.Progress = (this.cacheProgress + this.executeProgress) / 2;
            };

            minaClient = new MINAClient();
            minaClient.initConnection("127.0.0.1", 9123);
        }

        #region Properties

        private bool installEnabled;
        public bool InstallEnabled
        {
            get { return installEnabled; }
            set
            {
                installEnabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("InstallEnabled");
            }
        }

        private bool uninstallEnabled;
        public bool UninstallEnabled
        {
            get { return uninstallEnabled; }
            set
            {
                uninstallEnabled = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("UninstallEnabled");
            }
        }

        private bool isThinking;
        public bool IsThinking
        {
            get { return isThinking; }
            set
            {
                isThinking = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsThinking");
            }
        }

        private int progress;
        public int Progress
        {
            get { return progress; }
            set
            {
                this.progress = value;
                minaClient.sendMessage(value);
                RaisePropertyChanged("Progress");
            }
        }

        private int cacheProgress;
        private int executeProgress;

        public BootstrapperApplication Bootstrapper { get; private set; }

        #endregion //Properties

        #region Methods

        public void InstallExecute()
        {
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "See actually i've called install method");
            IsThinking = true;
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Install);
        }

        public void UninstallExecute()
        {
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "See actually i've called un-install method");
            IsThinking = true;
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall);
        }

        public void ExitExecute()
        {
            CustomBA.BootstrapperDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Method that gets invoked when the Bootstrapper ApplyComplete event is fired.
        /// This is called after a bundle installation has completed. Make sure we updated the view.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnApplyComplete(object sender, ApplyCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            IsThinking = false;
            InstallEnabled = false;
            UninstallEnabled = false;
            this.Progress = 100;
            ExitExecute();
        }

        void DetectComplete(object sender, DetectCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            Bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose,"fired! but does that give you any clue?! idiot!");
            if (LaunchAction.Uninstall == Bootstrapper.Command.Action)
            {
                Bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Invoking automatic plan for uninstall");
                Bootstrapper.Engine.Plan(LaunchAction.Uninstall);
            } 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method that gets invoked when the Bootstrapper DetectPackageComplete event is fired.
        /// Checks the PackageId and sets the installation scenario. The PackageId is the ID
        /// specified in one of the package elements (msipackage, exepackage, msppackage,
        /// msupackage) in the WiX bundle.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnDetectPackageComplete(object sender, DetectPackageCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PackageId == "UpdaterServiceInstallerId" || e.PackageId == "MosquittoInstallerId" || e.PackageId == "AppsInstallerId")
            {
                if (e.State == PackageState.Absent)
                    InstallEnabled = true;

                else if (e.State == PackageState.Present)
                    UninstallEnabled = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method that gets invoked when the Bootstrapper PlanComplete event is fired.
        /// If the planning was successful, it instructs the Bootstrapper Engine to 
        /// install the packages.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnPlanComplete(object sender, PlanCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Status >= 0)
                Bootstrapper.Engine.Apply(System.IntPtr.Zero);
        }


        #endregion //Methods

        #region RelayCommands

        private RelayCommand installCommand;
        public RelayCommand InstallCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (installCommand == null)
                    installCommand = new RelayCommand(() => InstallExecute(), () => InstallEnabled == true);

                return installCommand;
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand uninstallCommand;
        public RelayCommand UninstallCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (uninstallCommand == null)
                    uninstallCommand = new RelayCommand(() => UninstallExecute(), () => UninstallEnabled == true);

                return uninstallCommand;
            }
        }

        private RelayCommand exitCommand;
        public RelayCommand ExitCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (exitCommand == null)
                    exitCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExitExecute());

                return exitCommand;
            }
        }

        #endregion //RelayCommands
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var bundleVersion = Bootstrapper.Engine.VersionVariables["WixBundleVersion"];
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.